# The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install' returned a non-zero code: 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

My current folder is: `/home/user/Desktop/me/docker-kubernets`

1º Run commands:

```
docker run -it --rm --user "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
   -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app rails rails new --skip-bundle --api --database postgresql webapp

cd webapp
```

2º **webapp.conf**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name _;
  root /home/user/Desktop/me/docker-kubernets;

  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_user app;

  passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.4;
}
```

3º **rails-env.conf**

```
env SECRET_KEY_BASE;
env DATABASE_URL;
env DATABASE_PASSWORD;
```

4º **Dockerfile**

```
FROM phusion/passenger-ruby24
# Set correct environment variables.
ENV HOME /root
# Use baseimage-docker's init process.
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]
# Additional packages: we are adding the netcat package so we can
# make pings to the database service
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" netcat
# Enable Nginx and Passenger
RUN rm -f /etc/service/nginx/down
# Add virtual host entry for the application. Make sure
# the file is in the correct path
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
ADD webapp.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/webapp.conf
# In case we need some environmental variables in Nginx. Make sure
# the file is in the correct path
ADD rails-env.conf /etc/nginx/main.d/rails-env.conf
# Install gems: it's better to build an independent layer for the gems
# so they are cached during builds unless Gemfile changes WORKDIR /tmp
ADD Gemfile /tmp/
ADD Gemfile.lock /tmp/
RUN bundle install
# Copy application into the container and use right permissions: passenger
# uses the app user for running the application RUN mkdir /home/app/webapp
COPY . /home/user/Desktop/me/docker-kubernets
RUN usermod -u 1000 app
RUN chown -R app:app /home/user/Desktop/me/docker-kubernets
WORKDIR /home/user/Desktop/me/docker-kubernets
# Clean up APT when done.
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
EXPOSE 80
```

5º **setup.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Waiting PostgreSQL to start on 5432..."

while ! nc -z postgres 5432; do
  sleep 0.1
done

echo "PostgreSQL started"

bin/rails db:migrate
```

add the proper execution permissions for this file

```
chmod +x setup.sh
```

6º **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  webapp_setup:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - PASSENGER_APP_ENV=development
    entrypoint: ./setup.sh
  webapp:
    container_name: webapp
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - webapp_setup
    environment:
      - PASSENGER_APP_ENV=development
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/home/user/Desktop/me/docker-kubernets

  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.2
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
      - POSTGRES_USER=webapp
      - POSTGRES_DB=webapp_development
    volumes_from:
      - postgres_data
  postgres_data:
      image: postgres:10.2
      volumes:
        - /var/lib/postgresql/data
      command: /bin/true
```

7º Generate **Gemfile.lock**

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app ruby:2.4.2 bundle lock
```

8º `docker-compose build`

I'm getting the error:

```
Could not locate Gemfile
    ERROR: Service 'webapp_setup' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install' returned a non-zero code: 10
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made these changes in Dockerfile and it works like a charm:

```
FROM phusion/passenger-ruby24
# Set correct environment variables.
ENV HOME /root
# Use baseimage-docker's init process.
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]
# Additional packages: we are adding the netcat package so we can
# make pings to the database service
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" netcat
# Enable Nginx and Passenger
RUN rm -f /etc/service/nginx/down
# Add virtual host entry for the application. Make sure
# the file is in the correct path
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
ADD webapp.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/webapp.conf
# In case we need some environmental variables in Nginx. Make sure
# the file is in the correct path
ADD rails-env.conf /etc/nginx/main.d/rails-env.conf
# Install gems: it's better to build an independent layer for the gems
# so they are cached during builds unless Gemfile changes WORKDIR /tmp

COPY Gemfile* /tmp/
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN bundle install

# Copy application into the container and use right permissions: passenger
# uses the app user for running the application 
# RUN mkdir /home/me/Desktop/sg/docker-kubernets
COPY . /home/me/Desktop/sg/docker-kubernets
RUN usermod -u 1000 app
RUN chown -R app:app /home/me/Desktop/sg/docker-kubernets
WORKDIR /home/me/Desktop/sg/docker-kubernets

# Clean up APT when done.
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
EXPOSE 80
```

ruby version **Ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-linux]**

I hope be helpful!

Regards!